# Multiple lines printed out in an if else statement with String array. (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently coding my first World of Zuul game. I want to be able to build spring protection with some items that I have in my inventory.
But the problem I have is that when I want to print out my ArrayList in an if-else statement it prints out the "You build the spring protection!" several times. I only want it to print out 1 time.

Code:

```
String[] buildingSpring =  {"wood","pickaxe","pipes"};
// Build items
private void buildItem(Command command) {
    if (!command.hasSecondWord()) {      // If there is no second word, we don't know what to build
        System.out.println("Build what?");
        return;
    }
    String building = command.getSecondWord();
    switch (building)
    {
        case "spring":
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<buildingSpring.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0;j<inventory.size();j++)

                {
                    if(inventory.get(j).description.equals(buildingSpring[i]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("You build the spring protection!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> build spring
You build the spring protection!
You build the spring protection!
You build the spring protection!
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that will both work the same. As you may have figured out, it is printing three times because it is inside of a `for` loop. One option is to set a variable to `true` if the condition is met.

```java
boolean build = false; // 
for (int i = 0; i<buildingSpring.length;i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j<inventory.size();j++) {
        if(inventory.get(j).description.equals(buildingSpring[i]) && !build) {
            System.out.println("You build the spring protection!");
            build = true; // set to true
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want something else to happen inside of the `if` statement, you can just add a nested `if` statement that will check it has already been printed:

```
if(inventory.get(j).description.equals(buildingSpring[i])) {
    if (!build) {
        System.out.println("You build the spring protection!");
        build = true; // set to true   
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```

Don't forget to add `&& !build` to your `if` statement.

Your other option is to use a `break` statement  in conjunction with a label on the outermost loop to break out of the entire loop. Be aware, this will break out of the loop before it is finished, so if the only reason for the loop is to print "You build the spring protection!" this will do:

```java
outermost: // label as whatever you want, I chose "outermost"
for (int i = 0; i<buildingSpring.length;i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j<inventory.size();j++) {
        if(inventory.get(j).description.equals(buildingSpring[i])) {
            System.out.println("You build the spring protection!");
            break outermost; // breaking out of the outermost loop
        }
    }
}
```

Another note for the `break` example, you can also label the nested `for` loop too and that will also work if you don't want to break out of the entire loop.